# How to paginate subsections of an array property in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination, vuex

When displaying list data, one can iterate through the items using `v-for`. I have some filter controls which increase or decrease the number of visible items (size, type, name - stuff like that).

Regardless of this, I'd like to limit the amount visible on page to, say, 10 items.

In other words, if the filter hides 50 out of 100 result items (which are still stored in Vuex) I still want to be able to paginate through 5 pages (10 at a time only).

There's a few plugins [such as this one](http://hootlex.github.io/vuejs-paginator/) which seem to help with that.

However, I'd like to try to do it manually to understand how it's done, though I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: What have you tried so far? can you share your code and explain the what errors you are getting ?

Comment: You'd basically want to `slice` whatever you're iterating through. `results.slice(start, start + itemsPerPage)` and increase and decrease `start`.

Comment: By the way, **vuejs-paginator** pages the http.get() calls (so that memory footprint in minimized). Is this a feature you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have Vuex on board, a getter seems easiest.

```js
export const getters = {
  pagedItems: state => {
    return pageNo => {
      const pageSize = state.pageSize || 10
      const items = state.items || []
      return items.slice(pageNo * pageSize, pageSize) 
    }
  }
}
```

Default values (e.g `state.items || []`) are there to stop the calculation erroring before initial load completes.

Use it on the component in a computed property, which will make it reactive when pageNo changes,

```js
computed: {
  pagedItems() {
    return this.$store.getters['pagedItems'](this.pageNo)
  },
},
```

---

It just occurred to me that if you are filtering, you probably want to apply that ***before*** the pagination otherwise the display may not be be consistent in size (e.g page 1 filters to 4 items, page 2 to 6 items).

Depends on your exact filter, should be easy to add a getter for `filteredItems`  and use that as source for `pagedItems`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Barely tangientially related: if I have a set of multiple filters including a fuzzy search, how would one conceptually go about figuring out the ORDER in which they are applied / pick and choose which ones are applied to reduce potential memory and processing loads?

Comment: Interesting, that seems problematic with the getter solution. Let me have a think about it.

Comment: Wouldn't filtering simply alter the contents of the array in Vuex? That's kind of my initial instinct

Comment: My concern is that with an initial results array of 100,000,000 items this could start causing issues. This won't be the case ever, but you know what I mean.

Comment: I'm not sure how much of a problem that would be. See [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) which says 'The slice() method returns a shallow copy' and 'For object references (and not the actual object), slice copies object references into the new array'. So each filter makes a subset copy of the object reference list and leaves the original array as-is.

Comment: Great. Just dotting all the i's. Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

well, i would just divide the number of items by the number of data i want to display per page with the rest operator and create number of pages + 1, of course with some validations to empty data and so on.

Imagine you recieve an object that contains lists, this lists represent all the arrays with your data, each array is a row.

Just get the length, divide it with module operator and add one more, in your case, if you have 52 items, and want to have 10 per page:

52 % 10 = 2
52 / 10 = 5

you need 5 pages + 1 for the 2 items.

so i would do something like this:

```
const NUMBER_ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 10;

const numberItems = list.length;
const pages = numberItems / NUMBER_ITEMS_PER_PAGE

if(numberItems % NUMBER_ITEMS_PER_PAGE > 0) {
  pages++;
}

function buildPages(numberPages) {
  const pageObj = {}
  for(var i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
    pageObj.page[i+1]
    const arr = []
    for(var j = 0; j < (NUMBER_ITEMS_PER_PAGE) * (i + 1); j++) {
      arr.push(lists[i]) 
    }
   pageObj.page[i+1] = arr;
  }
}
```

of course this is just one possible solution, but i think this can let you start in some way, the code is just to help. good luck